# Lisp function that accepts two lists and returns inter product of them

Tags: list, lisp

This is for homework and I am confused where to start.
for example: 
list one is (1 2 3), list two is (3 4 6)
return 29 because (1 * 3) + (2 * 4) + (3 * 6)

Comment: Is this homework about practicing recursion with lists? and is that where your confusion is?

Comment: Where you start is by computing the inner product of a list by computing the inner product of their first elements and then adding it to the result of some function which computes the inner product of all the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Not spoiling the answer, but here is a hint of what you could expect to have:

```
(defun sum-lists% (x y z)  ...)
(defun sum-lists (x y) ... )
```

Trace both functions:

```
(trace sum-lists sum-lists%)
```

Your example:

```
(sum-lists '(1 2 3) '(3 4 6))

  0: (SUM-LISTS (1 2 3) (3 4 6))
    1: (SUM-LISTS% (1 2 3) (3 4 6) 0)
      2: (SUM-LISTS% (2 3) (4 6) 3)
        3: (SUM-LISTS% (3) (6) 11)
          4: (SUM-LISTS% NIL NIL 29)
          4: SUM-LISTS% returned 29
        3: SUM-LISTS% returned 29
      2: SUM-LISTS% returned 29
    1: SUM-LISTS% returned 29
  0: SUM-LISTS returned 29
```

And if you take care of corner cases, you can also have:

```
 (sum-lists '(1 2 3 4) '(3 4))

  0: (SUM-LISTS (1 2 3 4) (3 4))
    1: (SUM-LISTS% (1 2 3 4) (3 4) 0)
      2: (SUM-LISTS% (2 3 4) (4) 3)
        3: (SUM-LISTS% (3 4) NIL 11)
          4: (SUM-LISTS% (4) NIL 14)
            5: (SUM-LISTS% NIL NIL 18)
            5: SUM-LISTS% returned 18
          4: SUM-LISTS% returned 18
        3: SUM-LISTS% returned 18
      2: SUM-LISTS% returned 18
    1: SUM-LISTS% returned 18
  0: SUM-LISTS returned 18
```